# StringBuilder and JSONobject efficient conversions?

Tags: java, json, stringbuilder

I have a `StringBuilder` That represents a long `json` and a set of update rules for that json.
As I'm an external library, and each client will implement it's json parsing differently(`javax.json`, `jackson` etc.) For each update rule I call a

```
applyUpdate(StringBuilder json, String key, String Value)
```

But then, inevitably, the implementer will create a `jsonobject` from the `jsonString`, and then rebuild a StringBuilder and return it to me.
Can I somehow avoid it? I feel like a better design would solve the problem of implementing the json parsing in the client. (which is a must)

Comment: Do you need it to be a `StringBuilder`?  A `Map<String, Object>` (where `Object` is some JDK-internal representation of whatever json construct they include) would allow for implementation neutral modifications.

Comment: What would each element in the map represent? or a map with a single entry?

Comment: You said the `StringBuilder` ('s `String`) is a representation of a json object.  The keys would be the keys in this object, and the values would be some jdk representation of the members (`Map` for other json objects, `String` for strings, `BigInteger`/`BigDecimal` for numbers, `Boolean` for booleans, `List` for arrays, I think that's about it...).